# MYSQL TRIGGERS doesn't work

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER actiondelete_admin BEFORE DELETE ON actions_for_admins
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      DECLARE serv INT;
      DECLARE id INT;
      SET serv = (SELECT service_kind_id FROM services WHERE service_id = OLD.action_fk_service_id);

      SET id = (SELECT service_subs_fk_id FROM services WHERE service_id = OLD.action_fk_service_id);

      IF(serv = 1)THEN
          DELETE FROM facebook_service
          WHERE fb_id = id
      ELSE
          DELETE FROM  web_service
          WHERE web_id = id
      END IF;

      DELETE FROM services
      WHERE service_id = OLD.action_fk_service_id;

    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm trying to make trigger which deletes facebook service or web service. But I have error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE
          DELETE FROM  web_service
          WHERE web_id = id
      END' at line 13
```

Comment: Your `select` is missing a `from` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff

thank you. but I still  have error

Comment: You actually have numerous errors in your SQL syntax.

Comment: I think you also need to terminate the `DELETE` statements inside the `IF` using `;` (just like the other statements)

Answer (score 0):

The following may be useful:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `actiondelete_admin`//
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `actions_for_admins`//

CREATE TABLE `actions_for_admins` (
     `service_kind_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     `service_subs_fk_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     `action_fk_service_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)//

CREATE TRIGGER `actiondelete_admin` BEFORE DELETE ON `actions_for_admins`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE `serv`, `id`, `_action_fk_service_id` INT UNSIGNED;
  SET `_action_fk_service_id` := OLD.`action_fk_service_id`;

  -- SET serv = (SELECT service_kind_id FROM services WHERE service_id = OLD.action_fk_service_id);
  -- SET id = (SELECT service_subs_fk_id FROM services WHERE service_id = OLD.action_fk_service_id);

  SELECT `service_kind_id`, `service_subs_fk_id` INTO `serv`, `id`
  FROM `services`
  WHERE `service_id` = `_action_fk_service_id`;

  IF (`serv` = 1) THEN
    DELETE FROM `facebook_service` WHERE `fb_id` = `id`;
  ELSE
    DELETE FROM `web_service` WHERE `web_id` = `id`;
  END IF;

  DELETE FROM `services` WHERE `service_id` = `_action_fk_service_id`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef0d2e/1)</kbd>